# Nested set model optimization

Tags: mysql, model, nested, set

I have a website that contains ~100K pages (200-300 concurrent users). Each page has his own record in mysql InnoDB table - *page*:

```
page_id
page_parent
left_id
right_id
page_subject
page_children
page_depth
....
```

As you can see I use nested set model to display hierarchy of pages, etc etc.. Everything seems to be fine except performance of INSERT, UPDATE and DELETE statement. Moving page from one parent to another is extremely slow and sometimes takes ~30 sec (!!)

```
 CREATE PROCEDURE `PAGE_MOVE`(IN `pageSrc` INT, IN `pageDst` INT)
    LANGUAGE SQL
    NOT DETERMINISTIC
    CONTAINS SQL
    SQL SECURITY DEFINER
    COMMENT ''
BEGIN
    DECLARE srcLeftId INT;
    DECLARE srcRightId INT;
    DECLARE dstLeftId INT;
    DECLARE dstRightId INT;
    DECLARE width INT;

    SELECT left_id, right_id, right_id - left_id + 1
    INTO srcLeftId, srcRightId, width
    FROM page
    WHERE page_id = pageSrc;

    IF pageDst > 0 THEN
        SELECT left_id, right_id
        INTO dstLeftId, dstRightId
        FROM page
        WHERE page_id = pageDst;
    ELSE
        SELECT MAX(right_id) INTO dstLeftId FROM page WHERE page_parent = 0;
        SET dstRightId = dstLeftId + 1;
    END IF;

    IF dstLeftId > 0 THEN

        UPDATE page SET page_children = page_children - (width / 2)
        WHERE left_id < srcLeftId AND right_id > srcRightId;

        UPDATE page SET page_children = page_children + (width / 2)
        WHERE left_id <= dstLeftId AND right_id >= dstRightId;

        /**
         * Set nagative values to left_id and right_id (temporary)
         */
        UPDATE page
        SET left_id = -left_id, right_id = -right_id
        WHERE left_id >= srcLeftId AND right_id <= srcRightId;

        UPDATE page SET left_id = left_id - width WHERE left_id > srcLeftId;
        UPDATE page SET right_id = right_id - width WHERE right_id > srcRightId;

        UPDATE page SET left_id = left_id + width
        WHERE left_id >= IF(dstRightId > srcRightId, dstRightId - width, dstRightId);

        UPDATE page SET right_id = right_id + width
        WHERE right_id >= IF(dstRightId > srcRightId, dstRightId - width, dstRightId);

        SET @diff = IF(dstRightId > srcRightId, dstRightId - srcRightId -1, dstRightId - srcRightId - 1 + width);

        UPDATE page
        SET left_id = -left_id + @diff,
             right_id = -right_id + @diff
        WHERE left_id <= -srcLeftId AND right_id >= -srcRightId;
        /**
         * Set parent_id and page_depth
         */
        UPDATE page SET page_parent = pageDst, page_depth = GET_PAGE_DEPTH(page_id) WHERE page_id = pageSrc;

        /**
         * Update page_depth in children's nodes
         */
        IF width > 2 THEN

            SELECT left_id, right_id
            INTO srcLeftId, srcRightId
            FROM page
            WHERE page_id = pageSrc;

            UPDATE page
            SET page_depth = GET_PAGE_DEPTH(page_id)
            WHERE left_id >= srcLeftId AND right_id <= srcRightId;      
        END IF;


    END IF;
END
```

How could I optimize this procedure? Or maybe question should be: What is the alternative of using nested set model?

Function GET_PAGE_DEPTH():

```
CREATE FUNCTION `GET_PAGE_DEPTH`(`pageId` MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED)
    RETURNS smallint(6)
    LANGUAGE SQL
    DETERMINISTIC
    READS SQL DATA
    SQL SECURITY DEFINER
    COMMENT ''
BEGIN
    RETURN (
        SELECT COUNT(*) -1 AS depth
        FROM page AS parent
        INNER JOIN page AS node ON node.page_id = pageId
        WHERE node.left_id BETWEEN parent.left_id AND parent.right_id
    );
END
```

Hardware: Quad Core Q6600 (4x 2.40+ GHz), 4GB RAM

Thanks for any advice!

EDITED:

Table page looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `page` (
  `page_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `page_parent` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `left_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `right_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `page_module` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `page_connector` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `page_subject` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `page_title` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `page_path` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `page_text` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `page_children` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `page_depth` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `page_content` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `page_publish` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `page_published` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `page_unpublished` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `page_time` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `page_edit_time` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `page_delete` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `page_richtext` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `page_cache` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `page_template` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`page_id`),
  KEY `page_parent` (`page_parent`),
  KEY `left_id` (`left_id`),
  KEY `right_id` (`right_id`),
  KEY `page_depth` (`page_depth`),
  KEY `page_path` (`page_path`),
  KEY `page_connector` (`page_connector`),
  KEY `page_text` (`page_text`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: Can you post the structure of the table, it will help, particularly indexes.

Comment: ahhh, the joys of nested sets - perhaps things might have been simpler with the good olde adjacency list ??

Comment: I added full structure of the table. Maybe there is a different way to move page from one node to another?

Answer (score 2):

As a first step make sure you have seperate indexes for

page_id

page_parent

left_id, right_id

right_id

**EDIT**

SELECT MAX(right_id) INTO dstLeftId FROM page WHERE page_parent = 0;

The above query might be speeded up by having and index on (page_parent,right_id)

Other than that I can't really suggest much without having a much greater overview of the system and possibly modifying the way it works.

Comment: I have following indexes: page_id,page_parent,left_id,right_id. Should I have seperated indexes on (left_id,right_id) and right_id?

Comment: You have several occurences of " WHERE left_id <= -srcLeftId AND right_id >= -srcRightId;"  So I'd say yes you need (left_id, right_id) and right_id as two seperate indexes. Have you tried executing the individual queries to see which, if any, are particularly slow?

Comment: Every UPDATE statement on table "page" is slow when we have to update large amount of data, and MySQL has to update their table index :/ Anyway, this is disadvantage of nested set model :( Works fine until we have to insert new record as a child of some node.